# WebClient downloadfile

Tags: powershell, webclient

I have following PS script to download file using `WebClient`. The download links are in a text file. The download works, however, I want to make sure I don't overwrite duplicate files so I added additional code. The code runs good for single file. However, if duplicate is found then the code breaks with this error:

> Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."

The `Write-Host $newTarget` value looks like this:

> \\NRP-12-62-3\Root\NV-RST\Southwest Projects\Marketing Analysis\Monthly Sales Reports\10-01-2015-223403\Travis, Martin_17Jul14 17.42.45_Nature Mountain Daily Update 07-17-14.docx - duplicate 223541.msg

```
$docLinkFile = "c:\temp\urls.csv"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = $cred
$TargetDirectory = "\\NRP-12-62-3\Root\NV-RST\Southwest Projects\Marketing Analysis\Monthly Sales Reports" 
$subDirectoryName = $((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy-HHmmss'))
$TargetDirectory = $TargetDirectory + "\" + $subDirectoryName
# Create directory 
$subDirectory = New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $TargetDirectory
foreach ($i in Import-Csv $docLinkFile) {
  $fileURL = $i.DOC_URL
  Write-Host $fileURL
  $splitByslash = $fileURL.Split("/")
  # return the last element of the array
  $fileName = $splitByslash[-1]
  Write-Host $fileName -ForegroundColor Green
  $target = $TargetDirectory + "\" + $fileName    
  if (Test-Path $target) {
    $existingFileName = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($target)
    $extension = [io.path]::GetExtension($target)
    $newFileName = "$TargetDirectory" +"\" + $existingFileName + " - duplicate $(get-date -f HHmmss)" + "" + $extension        
    Write-Host $newFileName
    $webclient.DownloadFile($fileURL, $newFileName)
  } else {
    $webclient.DownloadFile($fileURL, $target)
  }
  Start-Sleep -s 1
}
```

Comment: There is no `Write-Host $newTarget` in your code. You output `$newFileName`, but you you try to download to `$newTarget`, which is `"$TargetDirectory\$newFileName"`.

Comment: If the `Root` share on `NRP-12-62-3` isn't root C:\ like it suggests then you could be hitting a file length ceiling of 255 characters. That whole path is 201 chars so if the share is buried a bit it's possible.

Comment: Great catch Ansgar. It's all good now. I updated the original code.

Answer (score 1):

Which PowerShell version do you use? Some people report that `System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile` works perfectly on Windows 2012 Server with PowerShell 4.0 but throws exception on Windows 8.

So, for file download purpose you may try `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet:

```
Invoke-WebRequest $fileURL -OutFile $target
```